# (2d) perlin-noise: dot product of a gradient and a direction vector

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket, linear-algebra

I am looking for a function that takes the coordinates of a current pixel and the coordinates of a corner (for a gradient), and returns the dot product of the gradient of that corner and the direction vector between the pixel and a corner. So the function would look like this: `dot-grid-gradient: number number number number -> number`

64 grids and 81 gradients:

[image]

I already made a list of 81 gradients whose x and y coordinates were between 0 and 1 and all randomly generated. A gradient would be the structure: eg. `(make-gradient 0.1223 0.8824)`. How would I implement something like this? I think my main problem is to "connect" the x and y values of a corner with its gradient.
Can someone help?

Thank you so much :)

Comment: The dot product of two 2D vectors is just `x1*x2 + y1*y2`.

Comment: Thank you. Like I mentioned, my main problem is: I have a list of gradients. Each of them gets a specific corner. And a corner has a x and a y value. My problem is to connect the x and the y of a corner with its gradient (which are in a list).

Comment: This is really unclear.  Can you illustrate what you mean?  (I mean graphically.)

Comment: Look at my (terrible) graphic above. It has 64 grids and 81 "corners" with its gradient. *And* I have a list of gradients eg. `(list (make-gradient 0.1223 0.8824)...)))` (81 gradients). Each corner is unique and has a specific place which can be found with an x and a y value. I need a way which connects a corner with an specific element of the list of gradients. So corner would get a gradient. In other words I need to finds a way which links an x and a y value (of the corner) to a element of the gradient list. (Sorry for the terrible explanation)

Comment: Unfortunately I still don't understand that :/  A gradient is just a vector representing a **direction** - it has no **position**.  So it's unclear what it means to "connect" a corner with an element of the list of gradients.  Perhaps a worked example would be a better way to illustrate what you mean?

Comment: OK, another try.  So we have the function `dot-grid-gradient: number number number number -> number`. It gets the coordinates of a pixel and the coordinates of a corner. I know, that a gradient isn't a position, but each corner represents a gradient in the list.. So in the function the x and the y value of a corner would represent the index of a list. So the function would take the x and the y value of a corner and substitute it with a gradient and would calculate the dot product.

Comment: Since each corner has its own gradient (remember we have 81 gradients in the list and 81 corners) I need to find out, how the function would index a list with an x and y value (corner).